# Authentication with Doctrine in Zend Framework 2 Good Practices

Tags: php, authentication, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Lets say that my page has 10 sections, in 6 of them I have to check if the user is logged in, and if not, redirect him to the "login/register" page.

I found myself repeating this code in the controller of those 6 pages:

```php
public function actionthatneedsauthAction()
{
    $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $authService = $sl->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');
    $user = $authService->getStorage()->read();  //is the user logged in?

    if ($user) {  //auth successful

    //-------------/*CODE FOR THIS SPECIFIC CONTROLLER GOES HERE*/--------

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'user' => $user,
            'somethingelse' => $somethingelse
        ));

    } else { //auth denied 
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(user, array('action' => 'login'));
    } 
}
```

I tried to encapsulate that into a service, called `islogged` (this is a model, not a controller), but I couldn't make it work because I couldn't find a way to redirect to a controller from inside a model, I only know how to redirect to a controller via another controller.

So in my `usermanager.php` I had a function like this one:

```php
public function islogged() 
{
    $sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $authService = $sl->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default'); 

    $user = $authService->getStorage()->read();  //is the user logged in?

    if ($user) {  //auth successful
        return $user;
    } else {
        /*
        redirect to the login screen, dont know how to do it,
        this code doesnt work here:

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL, array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action' => 'login'
        ));
        */
    }
}
```

so the idea was that in my controllers I only had to write:

```php
$user = islogged();
```

and all the code repetition I mentioned won't be necessary anymore.

Is it a good practice what I tried to do with the usermanager.php `islogged` function?
If it is a good practice, how am I supposed to redirect to a controller from inside a model?

If is not a good practice, which will be the way to avoid all that code repetition that I'm having in my controllers?

I know that I can put the authentication step into the `onboostrap()` but in that case the auth will be triggered for all of my pages, and I just want it in some of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to implement Doctrine Authentication with official `DoctrineModule Authentication` described in the `docs` folder of the repo.

Read this - [Link to DoctrineModule Authentication](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/authentication.md)

Then you can handle your Authentication check via the zf2 own Controller and View Helpers **identity**. See example in the `docs` [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/authentication.md#view-helper-and-controller-helper).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i had to do is replace these two lines:

```php
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');

$user = $authService->getStorage()->read();  //is the user logged in?
```

with this one:

```php
$user = $this->identity();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this ACL Module on my apps: https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac

My Customer overview controller then looks as so:

```
<?php
namespace RoleBasedCustomer\Controller;

use RoleBasedUser\Service\AuthenticationService;
use RoleBasedUser\Service\UserService;
use RoleBasedUser\Controller\AbstractMultiModelController;

class OverviewController extends AbstractMultiModelController
{

    public function __construct(
        AuthenticationService   $authService,
        UserService             $userService
    ) {
        $this->authService       = $authService;
        $this->userService       = $userService;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        if ( ! $this->authService->hasIdentity() ) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('customer/login');
        }



    }

}
```